# How to use functions from typescripts in other typescripts

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, import, reference, export

I'm a typescript beginner.
I want to use function's value from typescript in other typescript.

**lightpage.ts**

```
export class LightPage {

//light-on/off
private lightOn: boolean = false;

setLight(): boolean {
    this.lightOn = !this.lightOn;
    var lightResult = this.lightOn;
    console.log("lightResult : " + lightResult);
    return lightResult;
}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LightPage } from '../light/light';
@Component({

  selector: 'page-home',

  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    //let lp = new LightPage();


}
```

I want to use `setLight()`'s result value in `lightpage.ts` to `home.ts`!!

How can I import?

Comment: if you need a class method from outside without creating a object first you can simply build static methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I import?

Simple. In `home.ts` you will have:

```
import * from {LightPage} from './path/to/lightpage';
```

## More

This is ES6 import syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track but you can't declare a variable within a class (let). You should use it in your constructor or in any other function.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LightPage } from '../light/light';
@Component({

  selector: 'page-home',

  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    //let lp = new LightPage();
    private lp = new LightPage();

    constructor() {
        this.lp.setLight();
    }
}
```

Plus, I would rename your function setLight to toggleLight ;)